# Rig moves when switching action in action editor

Tags: animation, constraints, unreal-engine

I can't seem to get around this problem.

I have multiple animations in the same file and when I switch actions in the action editor the rig moves, but gets back into place as soon as I edit anything.

I wouldn't think to much of it, but when i export the animation in Unreal my frame 0 doesn't represent the actual frame 0 I have in blender for that animation and seems affected by that same weird bug.

Frame 0 in blender:
[image]

Frame 0 after switching action:
[image]
frame 0 in Unreal 4
[image]

Comment: Also if it can help with finding what's the problem, heres frame 0 in Unreal 4: https://imgur.com/a/ZireV

Comment: The little bones on floor in image 2, are they IK target bones for the feet?

Comment: Yes, the bones that goes to the heel in both feet are Ik bones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I tried fixing this issue by myself and found a work around, I had to delete all other actions from the file and now on export there was not this weird influence on the first frame. Not the most convenient fix, but a fix nonetheless :P.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this question answered though. I have the exact same problem as I'm trying to piece together a couple of actions into a larger sequence including moving the character's root half way in, when the walk cycle action starts. It seems Combine blending will destructively mess up some actions forever as far as NLA playback goes. I can play specific actions fine in the Action Editor, but they seem to behave completely irratinal when playing all in sequence. (I've keyed ALL bones in LocRot at the start and end of all actions. Currently using Blender 3.5.1/Win 11.)